# $ * * * * * echo "hi" => blado.kdb: command not found

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to set a cron job, namely echoing "hi" every minute.

When I do `* * * * * echo "hi"` I get `blado.kdb: command not found`. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Why does it start with a `$`? You know you need to use `crontab -e`? It looks like you're typing `* * * * * echo "hi"` directly in your shell which would explain why it tries to run `blado.kdb` which I assume is a file

Comment: The command I typed was just `* * * * * echo "hi"`, it was just to show it was executed from the terminal. You can't just type it directly into the shell? I didn't know that. So you always need to use a script?

Comment: @Bentley4: Commands typed directly into a terminal are executed in the terminal. How should the shell guess you are trying to set a crontab?

Comment: I thought everything done in the terminal was also picked up by the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run `crontab -e` in your shell. This opens a text editor
2. Only then type `* * * * * echo "hi"`. Save the file the text editor just opened for you

Your Cron task is now set

PS: `echo "hi"` will print "hi" in a void, if you want to see some results, set a task such as `* * * * * touch /tmp/foo`, and you'll see the modification date being updated every minute (`ls -l /tmp/foo`)